# How to find Nth element in a table?

Tags: selenium, xpath

The link I train on is: http://www.jigidi.com
//div[@class='text']/h4/b - finds the 1st cell's bold number

How can I Find the 2nd cell's bold number?
Is there a way to add something to the above code to tell Selenium to find not the 1st, but the 2nd div with class='text' in the DOM. 
For example something like: //div[1][@class='text']/h4/b

Or is there a more elegant way to Find the Nth element with class='text'. 
(Because the only thing I can think of is using the full xpath.)

Answer (score 2):

In different selenium language bindings there are usually methods to find a single element and multiple elements matching a locator. For example, in Python there are:

- [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath)
- [`find_elements_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath)

If you want to find the second element found by an xpath, use:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class='text']/h4/b')[1]
```

indexing starts from `0`.

In Java, there are:

- [`findElement()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By))
- [`findElements()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By))

The code you would use:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='text']/h4/b")).get(1)
```

---

You can also apply a pure XPath solution:

```
//div[@class='text'][2]/h4/b
```

or:

```
(//div[@class='text']/h4/b)[2]
```

There is a difference between the two, but both works in your case. Here indexing starts with `1`.

Comment: So far I am sticking to the IDE and looking for a pure XPath solution. The two xpath solutions you pointed are not working. I am using IDE 2.9.0

Comment: I am confused.  I tried the two XPath solutions. There are two more with bindings, but there isn't a 3rd xpath. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Simon Now, I'm confused. What do you mean by `two more with bindings`?

Comment: Two solutions more with bindings - one with Python and one with Java.  I need a pure XPath solution.

Comment: @Simon well, yeah, the xpath expressions at the end of the answer is something you should try in selenium ide.

Comment: Yes, I tried them and they are not working. That's what I meant with ''The two xpath solutions you pointed are not working. I am using IDE 2.9.0'' .

Comment: @Simon Please try to be helpful, "not working" does not explain anything. Do you get the wrong results? An error? Too many results, the correct one among them?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear *what exactly* you are trying to find - I'm glad to edit my answer if you'd like to find something else. Explaining it in terms of "cells" is not really helpful, there are `div` elements on that page, not `td`s. Please make this more clear by **showing** what you'd like to find.

The hard part of the solution is correctly placing parentheses `()` in the expression. The path expression with the correct semantics to find the *first* of those occurrences is

```
(//div[@class="text"]/h4)[1]/b
```

in plain English, it means

> find all `div` elements whose `class` attribute value is "text" and select their children `h4`. Of this intermediate sequence, select only the first result, and select its child elements called `b`.

and the result will be

```
<b>266</b>
```

You can test this e.g. in the Web Console:

```
> $x('(//div[@class="text"]/h4)[1]/b/text()')
```

yields

```
> Array [ #text "266" ]
```

---

In case you wanted to find the second `b` element, use `(//div[@class="text"]/h4)[2]/b`:

```
> $x('(//div[@class="text"]/h4)[2]/b/text()')
> Array [ #text "96" ]
```

Comment: @Simon So, does this answer your question? Or does my answer still need improvement?

Comment: I should have been more clear in the beginning what is not working. I understand your answer, but Selenium IDE returns: [error] locator not found: (//div[@class="text"]/h4)[2]/b.  For some reason the IDE is not happy with that syntax either.

Comment: @Simon That's a pity. The path expression is definitely correct, and it's the only way to have a "pure XPath solution". How do you invoke this expression in the Selenium IDE? Any code around it?

Comment: <td>storeText</td>
 <td> (//div[@class="text"]/h4)[2]/b</td>
 <td>puzzle2smallsize</td>